# migration failed m210613_145522_sortable_global_sets

Tags: migration

I am getting this error when processing the upgrade

- m210613_145522_sortable_global_sets

  - m210613_184103_announcements
  - m210829_000000_element_index_tweak

applying m210613_145522_sortable_global_sets
add column sortOrder smallint UNSIGNED AFTER `fieldLayoutId` to table {{%globalsets}} ...Exception: SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'sortOrder'
The SQL being executed was: ALTER TABLE `globalsets` ADD `sortOrder` smallint(6) UNSIGNED AFTER `fieldLayoutId` (/var/www/savillsplace/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Schema.php:676)
#0 /var/www/savillsplace/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Command.php(1307): yii\db\Schema->convertException()
#1 /var/www/savillsplace/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Command.php(1102): yii\db\Command->internalExecute()
#2 /var/www/savillsplace/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Migration.php(377): yii\db\Command->execute()
#3 /var/www/savillsplace/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/migrations/m210613_145522_sortable_global_sets.php(22): yii\

anyone please assist us on this issue

Answer (score 2):

This often happens when an update fails and the database isn't restored correctly before retrying the update.

Try to manually re-import your backup in an **empty** database (that's the important part), next, rename/remove your current `config/project` folder.

With your backup re-imported, run `php craft migrate/all` from your terminal and the migrations should complete properly this time.